# How to parse the value in blade laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-blade

**Parse the laravel array data Am tried not show any data?**
Please suggest to any other source?

here is the my dd Values in my laravel controller

```
array:2 [▼
  "count" => 5
  "date" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:5 [▼
      0 => "2019-11-04 15:41:53"
      1 => "2019-11-05 14:28:10"
      2 => "2019-11-12 13:47:31"
      3 => "2019-11-14 12:39:12"
      4 => "2019-11-17 10:54:39"
    ]
  ]
]
```

am unable to parse the value on blade my tried

`{{  $nov['date']['0']['0']  }}` ---- > here i get the exact value "2019-11-04 15:41:53" i need parse in dynamic data

```
@foreach ($nov as $key => $value)
    @foreach ($value as $key => $da)
    {{ $da }}
@endforeach @endforeach
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All the dates are in the key of `$nov['date'][0]`. So you've to make a loop by using this key instead of `$now`.

## Change in foreach loop and use `$nov['date'][0]` instead of direct `$nav`

```
@foreach ($nov['date'][0] as $key => $value)
    @foreach ($value as $key => $da)
    {{ $da }}
@endforeach
```

if you `print_r($now['date'])` you'll get

```
    0 => array:5 [▼
      0 => "2019-11-04 15:41:53"
      1 => "2019-11-05 14:28:10"
      2 => "2019-11-12 13:47:31"
      3 => "2019-11-14 12:39:12"
      4 => "2019-11-17 10:54:39"
    ]
```

and then if you access `0` index like `$now['date'][0]` then you will get the following data which you need to make a loop.

```
array:5 [▼
          0 => "2019-11-04 15:41:53"
          1 => "2019-11-05 14:28:10"
          2 => "2019-11-12 13:47:31"
          3 => "2019-11-14 12:39:12"
          4 => "2019-11-17 10:54:39"
        ]
```

Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop just the index 0 of date

```
@foreach ($nov['date']['0'] as $key => $value)
 {{ $value}}
@endforeach
```

If you want to loop all the date

```
@foreach ($nov['date']['0'] as $key => $value)
   @foreach ($value as $key => $da)
    {{ $da }}
  @endforeach 
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this one.

```
@foreach ($nov['date'] as $key => $value)
    @foreach ($value as $key => $da)
    {{ $da }}
@endforeach @endforeach
```